# Calculating length of each polygon side in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, length, measurements

In PostGIS, I want to calculate the length of different sides of a polygon. I know how to calculate a perimeter but how to calculate length side by side?

Perimeter is as a sum of side's length so I think PostGIS do this operation.

For example a basic polygon like this :

```sql
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS gid,
        'SRID=2154;POLYGON((0 1, 1 10, 20 30, 30 1, 0 1))'::geometry AS geom
)

SELECT
    gid,
    geom,
    ST_Perimeter(geom) AS perimeter
FROM
    data;
```

[image: polygon_sides]

What is the length between A and B, B and C, C and D, D and A?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595635/how-to-convert-polygon-data-into-line-segments-using-postgis :

```
SELECT st_length(ST_MakeLine(sp,ep))
FROM
   -- extract the endpoints for every 2-point line segment for each linestring
   (SELECT
      ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) as sp,
      ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom)  )) as ep
    FROM
       -- extract the individual linestrings
      (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(geom))).geom
       FROM yourtable
       ) AS linestrings
    ) AS segments;
```